# Is it possible to compile java project using maven jar plugin without packing classes to .jar?

Tags: java, maven

Basically i want to compile module using maven jar plugin and to create folder structure, compiled java classes, manifest, etc. without packing them into an archieve. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: `mvn clean compile`should give you what you want in the `target`directory.

Comment: Will that give you the full manifest including main-class and classpath though? Of course at the very least you could attach an antrunner task into the build lifecycle which unpacks the generated jar file again to some directory of choice.